# Difference between zmodload vs. autoload in Zsh

Tags: shell, zsh

What is the difference between commands `zmodload` and `autoload` in Zsh? They seem to be doing similar things and the manuals don't say much. Example:

```
zmodload zsh/terminfo
```

vs.

```
autoload -U zsh/terminfo
```

Answer (score 5):

Zsh's manuals do explain the difference (albeit not in one place):

- [`zmodload` loads a module supplied with Zsh itself.](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-zmodload) Modules are [written in the C programming language.](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/master/Src/Modules/terminfo.c)
- [`autoload` declares a function to be loaded *on demand* from your `$fpath`.](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html#Autoloading-Functions) Functions are written in Zsh’s own shell script language.

Since [`zsh/terminfo` is a Zsh-supplied module](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html), you should use `zmodload` to load it (and *not* `autoload`). Autoloading `zsh/terminfo` won’t do anything, because it’s not a function and it’s not written in shell script.

Note, that on most distributions of Zsh (such as the one included with macOS), certain Zsh modules are loaded dynamically when you try to use them, so you won’t even need `zmodload`. However, it’s not documented which ones and if you’re writing functions or scripts that are intended for wider distribution, then you cannot rely on this.